# Workflow not starting - 40100: Unauthorized.TrackingId

Tags: 2013, workflow, error

I've created a very simple (2013) list workflow in SharePoint Designer and successfully published it to my farm (single server). I've confirmed that the workflow is correctly registered with the list and is configured to start when a new item is created. However, this does not happen and looking in the server logs I see this error event (no error is displayed in the UI):

> Error processing management request. Method: POST, RequestUri: `http://e-sca-project:12291/NotificationManagement/$Notifications/?$expectedScopeRevision=0`, Error: System.TimeoutException: Could not successfully send message to scope '/SharePoint/default/da2dca86-5cfc-4b12-aaf3-a7c6b2396f1b/f6ebbb9a-2cfb-4cd6-b34c-6a62d137dcaf' despite multiple retries over a timespan of 00:05:05.8906824.. The exception of the last retry is: 40100: Unauthorized.TrackingId:cf1626bb-9563-46ac-ab20-26c945e40a95_GE-SCA-PROJECT,TimeStamp:28/08/2014 11:43:28.  ---> System.OperationCanceledException: 40100: Unauthorized.TrackingId:cf1626bb-9563-46ac-ab20-26c945e40a95_GE-SCA-PROJECT,TimeStamp:28/08/2014 11:43:28 ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 40100: Unauthorized.TrackingId:cf1626bb-9563-46ac-ab20-26c945e40a95_GE-SCA-PROJECT,TimeStamp:28/08/2014 11:43:28 ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 40100: Unauthorized.TrackingId:cf1626bb-9563-46ac-ab20-26c945e40a95_GE-SCA-PROJECT,TimeStamp:28/08/2014 11:43:28

At this point I cannot remove/detach the workflow from the list, nor delete it using Designer (it tells me it's been deleted but upon completion it's still there and editable). All out of the box workflows function as expected and a check of the farm workflow configuration hasn't turned up anything unexpected (for example, navigating to myserver:12291 shows the expected XML, all services are running, permissions are apparently correct etc.)

All suggestions gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user have permission based in a AD Group in the site or list, the workflow 2013 is not start. You need configure the permission explicit to user.

This bug exist only in workflow 2013, the workflow 2013 does not recognise permissions to AD Groups.